# Camera upside down on Windows (sometimes...)

Tags: opencv

I use OpenCV 2.4.13 with Qt 5 on Windows. My program takes a capture from a webcam with

```
cv::VideoCapture capture;
int test1=capture.open(0); // This returns 1 so it's ok.
capture >> frame;
```

It works very all the time on different computers with different Windows version (XP,Vista,7,8,10). However, today, on a Win7 computer, I had a weird bug. The first time I launched the program, it was ok. However, from time to time, the camera capture was upside down (I saw myself with my head downwards).

I restarted the computer and it worked well. Then I relaunched the program and it was upside down. From there it was always upside down. I launched Skype to test and the camera orienation was always OK.

Any ideas ??

Thank you so much,

Alex

Comment: There's very little detail here considering how specific an issue it is. For example, the first thing I'd expect to see is the concrete model of the camera. I would also expect to see the concrete version of OpenCV library, as there have been over dozen releases in just the 2.4 branch, and you haven't even narrowed it down to that.

Comment: Thank you. It's OpenCV 2.4.13, I don't have access to the camera model right now.

Comment: Was it some integrated camera (e.g. in a laptop), or an external one? If the latter, can you try it on a different machines (with both same and different os versions)? Does the camera have special drivers? Are those up to date?

Comment: It is an integrated camera on a laptop. I will check for the drivers update next week. However, regardless of the camera model, I can't think of any reason why this could happen. Especially because Skype always open the camera correctly I guessed the problem is not with the camera...

Comment: My first guess would be rather some subtle bug in driver or firmware, or some part of a standard not implemented fully or correctly -- wouldn't be the first nor last case of that happening. I expect the Skype client does a more thorough initialization (and have workarounds for various quirks).

Comment: Perfect, that's also my opinion. As you say, I guess the problem is with the camera driver but Skype must do something special and more advanced to avoid this. I will try to get a workaround. Thank you very much for your time.